# Flutter PopupMenuButton Missing Ripple Effect

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

[image]

The button in the above image is what I am attempting to reproduce.  When it is tapped, it should display a list of different temperature units.  I started out with a raised button and discovered that it's not easy to just display a popup list.  So I changed it to use a container.  It works except the ripple effect when tapping the button is missing.  If I remove the BoxDecoration color, it does work, but I do want the color of the button to be white.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: PopupMenuButton(
                          elevation: 3.0,
                          onSelected: (String value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selection = value;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            height: double.maxFinite,
                            width: double.maxFinite,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'C\n\nCelsius',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.grey[kButtonBorderShade],
                                    width: 0.5)),
                          ),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                              <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                            const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                              value: 'Value1',
                              child: Text('Choose value 1'),
                            ),
                            const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                              value: 'Value2',
                              child: Text('Choose value 2'),
                            ),
                            const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                              value: 'Value3',
                              child: Text('Choose value 3'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

Edit: Thank you for the answer below.  I got this working exactly the way I wanted with the advice given.  Here is my final button:

```
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: PopupMenuButton(
                              onSelected: (String value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _selection = value;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                        color:
                                            Colors.grey[kButtonBorderShade],
                                        width: 0.5)),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'C\n\nCelsius',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
                                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: 'Value1',
                                  child: Text('Choose value 1'),
                                ),
                                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: 'Value2',
                                  child: Text('Choose value 2'),
                                ),
                                const PopupMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: 'Value3',
                                  child: Text('Choose value 3'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that wrapping the `PopupMenuButton` with `Material` and put the `color` property in the `Material` widget instead of the `BoxDecoration`, like this:

```
Material(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: PopupMenuButton(...
```